# ResouceManager got stucked in Accepted State

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-hadoop

[image]I am trying to integrate my es 2.2.0 version with hadoop HDFS.In my envoirnment,I have 1 master node and 1 data node. On my master node my Es is installed.
   But while integrating it with HDFS my resource manager applications jobs get stuck in Accepted state.
   Somehow i found link to change my yarn-site.xml settings:

```
   <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
   <value>2200</value>
   <description>Amount of physical memory, in MB, that can be allocated for containers.</description>
   </property>

   <property>
   <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
   <value>500</value>
   </property>
```

I have done this also but it is not giving me expected output.

Configuration:-

my core-site.xml

```
   <property> 
   <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>          
   <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
   <description>A base for other temporary directories.
   </description>  </property> 

   <property> <name>fs.default.name</name> 
   <value>
   hdfs://localhost:54310
   </value> 
   <description>The name of the default file system. A URI whose scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation. The uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming the FileSystem implementation class. The uri's authority is used to determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.
    </description> 
    </property>
```

my mapred-site.xml,

```
  <property> 
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>  
  <value>localhost:54311</value> 
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs at. If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map and reduce task. </description> 
  </property>
```

my hdfs-site.xml,

```
   <property> 
   <name>dfs.replication</name> <value>1</value> <description>Default block replication. The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created. The default is used if replication is not specified in create time. </description> 
    </property>
```

Please help me how can i change my RM job to running state.So that i can use my elasticsearch data on HDFS.

Comment: Logs, we need logs.. Try to extract relevant data from: /var/log/hadoop-yarn/yarn-yarn-resourcemanager-mpenode1.cern.ch.log

Answer (score 0):

If the screenshot is correct - you have 0 nodemanager - thus the application can’t start running - you need to start at least 1 nodemanager, so that application master and later tasks can be started.

Comment: Thanks for reply,I have corrected it now my nodemanager is working.But it is still stucked in Accepted state.